# making print remove div font/style

Tags: javascript, html, printing

i didnt find it at all on search...
I have a page with a div that shows the data chosen to print on a thermal printer.
I'm using a simple js to print it.
It works, but my thermal printer its printing it poorly, and some other posts point that if you just send it print, it will try to print a bit like images, making it unreadable.
So, what I hope to make its to modify the print js code to transform it to text (keeping the table/line order) before send it to print. If possible, I want to force the page to refresh it after print.

print.js

```
 document.getElementById("doPrint").addEventListener("click", function() {
 var printContents = document.getElementById('printMe').innerHTML;
 var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
 document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
 window.print();
 document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
 });
```

I'm self learner, so if i didnt make it clear enough i hope friends will bear with me.
Of course, if you have other alternatives that works, i'm open to it.

Comment: From what I gathered, you want a specific look when you print. I only know how to do that in CSS. You add a `@media print {}` with specific CSS styles for printing. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media

Comment: Well, it didnt worked (because of my print js code) but your comment made me realize that i could use css to do it. Thanks, i have made Lucida Console my primary font on css and worked just fine to print on thermal printer.